# Change Language Output for \citeauthor \citeyear

Tags: citing, german, english

First of all I want to say that I have no idea about LaTeX and its structure. I'm writing my thesis and I'm forced to use LaTeX.

So far so good.

My template was in German and I have to write my thesis in English

I got a `thesis.tex` file where all settings are written... I guess?

I'm using the citing methods `\cite` and also `\citeauthor \citeyear` which both work fine. The only problem I have is that `\citeauthor \citeyear` gives me the output in German: e.g.
`\citeauthor{ccelik2011extending} \citeyear{ccelik2011extending}` gives

> Celik und Yilmaz (2011)

How can I change the "und" from German to English and make it print "and"?

```
\documentclass[openany]{vutinfth} % Remove option 'final' to obtain debug information.


% Load packages to allow in- and output of non-ASCII characters.
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
          \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
          \usepackage[autostyle,english=guillemets,english=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}   
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}   
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{nag}       
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./graphics/} }


\newcommand{\authorname}{NAME}
\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Title}

% Set PDF document properties
\hypersetup{
    pdfpagelayout   = TwoPageRight,           
    linkbordercolor = {Melon},               
    pdfauthor       = {\authorname},          
    pdftitle        = {\thesistitle},        
    pdfsubject      = {Subject}, 
    pdfkeywords     = {a, list, of, keywords} 
}


\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 

\nonzeroparskip            
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\makeindex      
\makeglossaries
\setauthor{xy}{xy}{}{male}
\setadvisor{xy}{xy MSc.}{}{male}


\setaddress{Address}
\setregnumber{xy}
\setdate{18}{07}{2019} % Set date with 3 arguments: {day}{month}{year}.
\settitle{\thesistitle}{Titel der Arbeit}
\setsubtitle{xy}{}

% Select the thesis type: bachelor / master / doctor / phd-school.
% Bachelor:
%\setthesis{master}
%
% Master:
\setthesis{master}
\setmasterdegree{master}


\setcurriculum{xy}
{xy}



\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\textbf{TODO: {#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter



\addtitlepage{english} % English title page.


\begin{abstract}
abstract


\end{abstract}


\selectlanguage{english}


\tableofcontents % Starred version, i.e., \tableofcontents*, removes the self-entry.



\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{parts/01_introduction}


\input{parts/02_Background}

\input{parts/03_SystematicLiteratureReview}

\input{parts/04_MethodEmpiric}

\newpage

\listoffigures % Starred version, i.e., \listoffigures*, removes the toc entry.


\listoftables % Starred version, i.e., \listoftables*, removes the toc entry.



\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider creating an MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/237192) to help us help you.

Comment: somewhere your template sets up things for german. Search your template for "german" and change that to english. And ask whoever forced you to use latex and this template for some support.

Comment: i have inserted the code of the .tex file and removed most coments in there 
i hope you can help me out now as the support of the template does not answer atm

Comment: Usually `babel` is responsible for your document language settings. Your file has `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}`, which loads both English and German (new orthography rules). The last language passed to `babel` is the main document language, so in your case your document is in German. If you want English, switch to `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}`.

Comment: BTW: The package list of the template does not look great. Packages should only be loaded once. Ideally all loaded packages should actually be used (do you need `lipsum` to generate dummy fill text in your thesis?). `hyperref` should generally be loaded last (there are a few exceptions, and I think `apacite` is one of them, but the template definitely loads `hyperref` too early - and too ften)

Comment: hey @moewe thank you for your solution 
i tried using `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}` but it did not change anything
i used to create dummy text, not anymore but is it a big of a deal to have it in there? i dont undertand the hyperref parts .. .also idk what it does to be honest :P

Comment: Hmmm. In theory that should work. But of course there could be other bits of your code that we don't see at the moment that works against this? Do you have any more random `\selectlanguage`s anywhere in your document? (There is one after the `abstract`.) Maybe one of them switches back to German? Any more mentions of `ngerman` or `german`?

Comment: `\selectlanguage{english}` i have this one time after the abstract,

`ngerman` and `german` are not given in that file besides in coments,

there are other files in the template which i do not know what they are for they are .cls and .dtx files

Comment: i solved it!
there was another `\RequirePackage[naustrian,english]{babel}´ in this .cls file, 
i changed the sequence of naustrian and english and it worked! thank you @moewe

Comment: Ugh. Whoever wrote the class and then decided it should be used also for English works should get a stern talking to. Hard coding document language in the class files is rarely a good idea.